# html/php SQL populated nav bar not

Tags: php, html, sql, nav

this is my php code for populating my nav bar through an SQL query. I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'index' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/hj016/public_html/SKSSTW/index1.php on line 102

```
<?php
$sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages "; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query )) 
{    
echo "<li><a href="index.php?pid=".$row['linklabel'].>".$row['linklabel']."</a></li>";     
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
echo "<li><a href="index.php?pid=".$row['linklabel'].>".$row['linklabel']."</a></li>";
```

to

```
echo '<li><a href="index.php?pid='.$row['linklabel'].'">'.$row['linklabel'].'</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with double quotes, you are closing the `echo` string because you are not escaping them.

I recommend you to use simple strings for the `echo` function:

```
echo '<li><a href="index.php?pid="'.$row['linklabel'].'>"'.$row['linklabel'].'"</a></li>';
```

If you are using double quotes, you can also use `{` `}` combined with the escaping tag `\`:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?pid=\"{$row['linklabel']}\">{$row['linklabel']}</a></li>';
```

Another escaping option opening and closing tags would be:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?pid=".$row['linklabel']."\">".$row['linklabel']."</a></li>";
```